# Updating column in database using entity framework core

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I have some problems with updating records in database.
I have a code, which adding data in DB

```
foreach (var todatabase in InitialAllWeights)
{
    if (sd.stationSeasonNNcoefs.Count(e => e.Hours == todatabase.Hours && e.SeasonId == todatabase.SeasonId && e.StationId == todatabase.StationId) == 0)
    {
         sd.Add(todatabase);
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
sd.SaveChanges();
```

and if in database we havent the initial count we adding the current data. As for my task, I need to add data if the count empty, and update data if the count is full, but if it full i must update only one column `WeightsSeason`.

```
public class stationSeasonNNcoef
{
    public int stationSeasonNNcoefID { get; set; }
    public int StationId { get; set; }
    public int SeasonId { get; set; }
    public string WeightsSeason { get; set; }
    public int Hours { get; set; }

}
```

and another column (`SeasonId, StationId, Hours`) must stay without changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is how you uniquely identify the potential record to update (or insert if not found):

```
e.Hours == todatabase.Hours && e.SeasonId == todatabase.SeasonId && e.StationId == todatabase.StationId
```

Then first try to get that record.  If it's found, update it.  If not, insert it.  Perhaps something like this:

```
var record = sd.stationSeasonNNcoefs.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Hours == todatabase.Hours && e.SeasonId == todatabase.SeasonId && e.StationId == todatabase.StationId);
if (record == null)
{
    sd.Add(todatabase);
}
else
{
    record.WeightsSeason = todatabase.WeightsSeason;
}
sd.SaveChanges();
```

The call to `SingleOrDefault` will either return the one matching record or `null` if no matching record is found.  (Note: It will throw an exception if more than one is found.)